# Change default homepage Magento ver. 2.1.1

Tags: magento2, theme, configuration, magento-2.1, home

I have installed sample data on magento(Madison Island), It has default homepage set. I have created new page called test (cms>pages>create page).

When I open my localhost, **test page should appear first rather than homepage of madison island**. How can i do it?

Answer (score 8):

Change home page under `Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change home page in magento-1.9 version.

1. create page at Login to admin-->cms-->pages-->add new
2. Goto system-->configuration-->General-> Web-->default pages-->select from here.

If you want to change home page in magento-2 version.

1. Login to admin panel
2. Admin-->Stores-> Configuration-> General-> Web-> Default Pages > CMS Home Page

Comment: For M2 this answer is a bit misleading. There IS a dropdown from which you can select a CMS page to be the "CMS Home Page".

Answer (score 0):

it's better to change "Home Page Block" block under Content > Blocks in Admin page